# ARJ library in .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, compression, arj

Is there any open source/free library in .NET (C#) for processing arj files. I need to compress files in arj.

I have done some basic search on Google, but cannot find any!

Answer (score 1):

For **unpacking** I did my own user friendly wrapper for 7zip:
https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor

```
using (ArchiveFile archiveFile = new ArchiveFile(@"Archive.ARJ"))
{
    foreach (Entry entry in archiveFile.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.FileName);

        // extract to file
        entry.Extract(entry.FileName);

        // extract to stream
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        entry.Extract(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [7zip wrapper](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/), but is allows only unpacking of ARJ.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the library that will let you do this, you can dig in the file format specification:

http://www.fileformat.info/format/arj/corion.htm

then I'm sure you'll find .Net libraries for the compression methods that this file format can use.

Also, after a quick look at it, I think it won't be much work to implement the format

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARJ), there is an [opensource version](http://arj.sourceforge.net/) of it. You could just run that from the command line, I think.